# How can I create a new socket in /dev?

Tags: application-development, programming, udev, sockets

I want to create a new socket file in `/dev`. Does the way to get it is adding a new rule to `udev`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

- The usual way to create a Unix domain or TCP socket is **programatically**, via the [*mknod*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man2/mknod.2.html) or [*socket*](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man2/socket.2.html) system calls. The [`mknod` command](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mknod.1.html) will **not** allow you to create a socket.

#### From the command line, use the *socket* package

- If you wish to create a Unix/TCP socket **from the command-line**, try the `socket` command from the *socket* package (install it first). Summarizing its [man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/oneiric/man1/socket.1.html) description:

  > Socket  creates  an Internet domain TCP or a UNIX domain stream socket and connects it to stdin and stdout.

#### Examples of *socket* usage (from man page)

1. `socket -v coma.cs.tu-berlin.de nntp`

   connects   to   the   nntp  port  (port  119)  of  coma.cs.tu-berlin.de
      (130.149.28.10).
2. `socket -sl 3425`

   creates a server socket on port 3425 on the local host and waits for  a
      connection.   After  a  connection has been closed, a new connection is
      accepted.
3. `socket -wslqvp "echo Socket! " 1938`

   creates a server socket on port 1938 on the local host and waits for  a
      connection.   When  a  connection  is accepted, the string "Socket!" is
      written to the socket.  No data is read from the socket and written  to
      the  finger  program.   The  connection  is  closed when an end-of-file
      condition at the standard output of the program  occurs.   Then  a  new
      connection is accepted.

Comment: Have you any idea how you would create the equivalent of `/dev/log` with the `socket` command?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create it, but you can copy from a working system as below to some shared location between the machines and copy from the shared location to the other system.

Machine A

```
cp -rf /dev/SRC shared_directory
```

Machine B

```
cp -rf shared_directory /dev/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your looking for the command [`mknod`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/mknod.1.html). (If you're interested in the system call it uses, [here's the manpage for that](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man3/mknod.3posix.html).)

Comment: `mknod` does not permit to create socket file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `socat`:

```
socat UNIX-LISTEN:/dev/my.socket -
```